# Text box breaking container in mobile view

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have used my custom framework for responsive.
In mobile view less than (768px resolution) textbox is breaking my container. It goes oustside the container and not considering the container padding.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-3">
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="col-3">
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="col-3">
<input type="text" />
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS :

```
* { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
.container { width:1170px; margin:0px auto;  }
.col-3 { float:left; width:30%; margin-right:3%; background:#CCC;  }
input { border:0px none; background:#333; height:30px; line-height:30px; width:100%; color:#FFF; padding:0px 10px; }

@media (max-width:767px)
{
.container { width:auto; padding:0px 10px; }
.col-3 { float:none; width:100%; margin-bottom:10px }
}
```

[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/gbgB4/30/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just use box-sizing: border-box; in your input CSS file.

So your code will be:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-3">
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="col-3">
<input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="col-3">
<input type="text" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
* { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
.container { width:1170px; margin:0px auto;  }
.col-3 { float:left; width:30%; margin-right:3%; background:#CCC;  }
input { border:0px none; background:#333; height:30px; line-height:30px; width:100%; color:#FFF; padding:0px 10px; box-sizing: border-box; }

@media (max-width:767px)
{
.container { width:auto; padding:0px 10px; }
.col-3 { float:none; width:100%; margin-bottom:10px }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input width is currently `100% + padding` making it more than 100% of it's parent. To prevent this you need to change the `box-sizing` property to `border-box` from the default `content-box`:

```
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbgB4/31/)

[FURTHER READING](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Thanks for the help,but, this property is not working in IE. Do you have any other solution than please let me know

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` works since IE8. What version are you using?